# Chartist.js label styling - primarily padding/margin

Tags: chartist.js

I need to able to add some extra styling to x-axis labels - primarily to give them a little more vertical separation from the chart area. CSS doesn't seem to work for this particular use case.

Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Here's a screenshot of the current issue: https://puu.sh/BuMUE/91183fcbdf.png

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can add some space to those x-axis via JavaScript or CSS, I assume you mean to separate them from the dotted lines right? In that case you can use the offset property in the options when you are creating a new instance of your chart:

```js
var data = {
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],  
  series: [
    [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
  ]
};

var options = {
    classNames: {
        chart: 'ct-chart',
        series: 'ct-series',
        label: 'ct-label'
    },    
    axisX: {
        offset: 70 //Insert here your axisX offset and play with the values
    },
    axisY: {
        offset: 55 //Insert here your axisY offset and play with the values
    }
};

var barChart = new Chartist.Bar('#someBarGraphID', data, options);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.css">
<div id="someBarGraphID"></div>
<script src="bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.js">
```

Then if you want a CSS solution, you can always tackle that by selecting the classes of the chart when is created, just try something like:

```
#someBarGraphID .ct-label .ct-horizontal {
    //Apply CSS to xAxis
}

#someBarGraphID .ct-label .ct-vertical{
    //Apply CSS to yAxis
}
```

Comment: offset in the config worked. CSS doesn't in this case as I'm trying to add margin to the bottom of the labels. They simply don't move. 

Also, while the offset is a passable solution, it doesn't add any to the height of the overall chart space so after about 20px, they start to push out the top of the visible svg area.